# Install metabase using cmd

Tags: java, cmd, windows-10, metabase, nssm

Using windows 10 cmd, i am trying to install metabase.

```
nssm install metabase C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe AppDirectory C:\Program Files (x86)\POS -jar metabase.jar
```

It is installed successfully.

[image: img]

but when i try to start service.

```
sc start metabase
```

But it doesn't start.

Why does this happen? What am I missing here? please help me. thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
According to the comment i used double quotes around paths.

```
nssm install metabase "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\POSPReports" "-jar metabase.jar"
```

[image: error]

Then I tried to start service manually. But giving following an error.

Comment: __"But it doesn't start."__ can you clarify please? "Does not start" is a bit vague. What does it do or does it not do? I am also a little concerned that you have no double quotes around paths with spaces as cmd sees each space as a separator if not in double quotes.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Hello sir, I have updated my question and added more details. please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You would probably need to uninstall it and install it again. Do not quote the -jar portion, just try it as `nssm install metabase "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\POSPReports" -jar metabase.jar`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I did same what you said, but still gives same error. Thank you for your effort sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much [Gerhard Barnard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818749/gerhard-barnard) for helping me. I solved my issue.

First, I installed my metabase service using following command.

```
nssm install metabase "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe" -jar metabase.jar
```

And then set the startup directory.

```
nssm set metabase AppDirectory "C:\Program Files (x86)\POS"
```

Hope it will help someone.